# What was the price of gunpowder in Victorian England

Tags: weapons, victorian, price

What was the price of gunpowder in Victorian England? Any quantity will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Sketch of the Mode of Manufacturing Gunpowder at the Ishapore Mills in Bengal:](https://books.google.com/books?id=YwxAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PR14&dq=cost%20gunpowder%20england&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilidyPzqvSAhVliFQKHSUfCTgQ6AEIRjAI#v=onepage&q=cost%20gunpowder%20england&f=false) Published in 1862.

> The English service powders cost 5£. upwards for the 100 lbs say 50
>   rupees. The best sporting powders sell in London about 2s to 3s per lb, 
>   10£. to 15£. the 100 lbs. Blasting powder is sold by dealers at from
>   50s to 75s per 100 lbs.

The entire book discusses the manufacture of powder, and the facility is in India, but it mentions prices in London, so they should be relevant.

Comment: To clarify, is this saying that gunpowder cost 2-3 shillings per pound?

Comment: Yes, in 1862. Ill edit the date into the answer to clarify.

Comment: The start of that book lists booksellers with roughly one per country.  So America gets two: one in New York for Federal States and one in Richmond for Confederate States