# How much did gunpowder cost per barrel in 1605 in London?

Tags: price

I'm trying to work out how much the 32 barrels of gunpowder placed under the Houses of Parliament by the gunpowder plot conspirators cost at the time, then want to come up with an equivalent cost in modern money.

Comment: A later (~1862) figure can be found [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/35692/16951)

Comment: Welcome to History:SE. Could you edit your question to clarify what you've looked into already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site tour and Help Centre and, in particular, How to Ask.

Comment: @justCal: In real terms at least, one can expect that gunpowder cost much more in pre-Industrial Revolution 1605 than it did in mid-Second Industrial Revolution 1860's London.

Comment: [This source](http://james.wardware.com/J-Europ-Econ-Hist.pdf) on pages 20-21 lists early 1500's prices for gunpowder in the Netherlands. The short distance to London, plus arbitrage, would ensure that prices were comparable in the two locations i expect. One could expect prices in 1605 to be intermediate to the prices in the early 1500's and the 1860's.

Answer (score 5):

In ["*A History of Agriculture and Prices in England: 1583-1702*" by james Edwin Thorold Rogers](https://books.google.ca/books?id=iwRGAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false), pp738, one finds various references to gunpowder prices recorded by Samuel Pepys as:

- 1589: *8d.* / pound
- 1642: *2s.* / pound
- average of 15 entries over the period:

  - *14s. 3½d.* / dozen pounds
  - *£6 5s.* / cwt

Specific prices for purchase by the barrel, for naval stores, are also given:

- 1653: *79s. 6d.* / barrel
- 1654:

  - *79s. 6d.* / barrel
  - *75s.* / barrel
  - *72s. 6d.* / barrel

Comment: Let's round to 4£/barrel in 1653 then.  128£ for the 32 barrels.  Convert 128£ in 1650 to 13,250.20£ in 2017 https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/currency-converter/  1650 is not 1605 but getting there...